# pandas removes rows with nan in df

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a `df` that contains `nan`,

```
A  
nan  
nan
nan
nan
2017
2018
```

I tried to remove all the `nan` rows in `df`,

```
df = df.loc[df['A'].notnull()]
```

but `df` still contains those `nan` values for column `'A'` after the above code. The `dtype` of `'A'` is `object`.

I am wondering how to fix it. The thing is I need to define multiple conditions to filter the `df`, and `df['A'].notnull()` is one of them. Don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tired [`df = df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)?

Comment: Are you sure those are null values and not strings or objects. I would guess not since your numerical values are integers, not floats and nan is a float value.

Comment: @A.Kot the `dtype` is `object` for `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide a reproducible example. As such this works:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.nan], [np.nan], [2017], [2018]], columns=['A'])
df = df[df['A'].notnull()]

df2 = pd.DataFrame([['nan'], ['nan'], [2017], [2018]], columns=['A'])
df2 = df2.replace('nan', np.nan)
df2 = df2[df2['A'].notnull()]

# output [df or df2]
# A
# 2017.0 
# 2018.0
```